# Browser Specific Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have had to write some JQuery specifically for IE6, fixes some bugs with compatability between IE6 and IE8. However I only want to apply the IE6 JQUERY to IE6 and not have it load with IE8.

Can anyone suggest a way of detecting IE6 and running the IE6 Specific JQUERY?

Comment: What is the thing that you fixed?

Comment: :hover, switching some images based on version, other bits and pieces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="your_ie6_specific_script.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

You could also do this programatically:

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version === '6.0') {
    alert('ie 6.0');
}
```

Comment: How do other (non-IE) browsers deal with this tag? Surely they would not recognise it and thus end up loading the script anyway?

Comment: To other browsers, it's just an HTML comment, so they will ignore the script tag.